# sed variable expansion not working (unterminated `s' command)

Tags: sed

I have a file named config.yaml that contains this line:

```
device_connection_string: "<ADD DEVICE CONNECTION STRING HERE>"
```

I want to replace
 `<ADD DEVICE CONNECTION STRING HERE>` with the value of the following variable:

```
root@ubuntu1804-ko-001:/tmp# echo "$CSTRING"

HostName=PulseAzure-BetterTogetherDemo.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=ubuntu1804-ko-001;SharedAccessKey=xdWDu2gnzlg8X1mHgGqYU+yECBYUJ065n1AjdkYNCWI=
root@ubuntu1804-ko-001:/tmp#
```

When I run this sed command, I get the unterminated s error:

```
sed -i "s/<ADD DEVICE CONNECTION STRING HERE>/$CSTRING/g" config.yaml
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unterminated `s' command
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does your `CSTRING` have an extra trailing newline by any chance? Please [edit] your question to include the output of `echo "$CSTRING" | xxd` (being sure to include the quotes)

Comment: Looks like it might be a preceding newline...?  Updated Question via edit.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that would do it also

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!!  Is there some way I can give you credit when marking this as answered...?  (I'm new here).

Comment: Thanks - I have added a brief answer below in case someone else finds it useful

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `CSTRING` contains a literal newline.

By enabling shell debugging we can see what `sed` sees:

```
$ set -x
$ sed "s/<ADD DEVICE CONNECTION STRING HERE>/$CSTRING/g" config.yaml
+ sed 's/<ADD DEVICE CONNECTION STRING HERE>/
HostName=PulseAzure-BetterTogetherDemo.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=ubuntu1804-ko-001;SharedAccessKey=xdWDu2gnzsfsdfdsfds=/g' config.yaml
```

and it's the `sed 's/<ADD DEVICE CONNECTION STRING HERE>/` that is causing the

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unterminated `s' command
```

error.